# Two part question with npm install and what it does

Tags: node.js, npm

If team developer A installs a package:

```
npm install a-cool-package
```

And then pushes his/her code to the repo.

Developer B does a `git pull` to get the updated package.json and package-lock.json and any files that changed (presumably to use the cool package).

Then Dev B needs to say `npm install` to use the latest version of the app.

What is the purpose of this? Is it to get your local node_modules folder updated with the cool package and all its dependencies? I assume that's true because you don't include node_modules in the repo. Am I right?

Part 2:
When Dev B does a `npm install`, all packages that have updates will be updated (ie only the minor and patch levels for the typical settings).

Is there an alternative if you don't want to potentially break things but you need what Dev A has? Or do you just always run `npm install` after the package.json is changed and hope nothing breaks?

I find myself confused about what the typical workflow should be to ensure minimal downtime and sharing of code. I worry that updates to packages will have breaking changes, and all I did was run install to get what another developer has.

Or should I be doing npm install for the specific package he installed? `npm install a-cool-package`

Answer (score 1):

## Part 1 - about NPM and dependencies

NPM is a package manager. It manages the packages, which are your dependencies. Those live in the `node_modules` directory.

You don't commit `node_modules`, because dependencies can be big, and sometimes (with addons) they only work on the machine on which they were installed. Another reason to avoid committing the dependencies is that someone might modify them, and then your project will break when you DO update the package.

TL;DR. Yes. `npm install` (short form: `npm i`) installs the packages listed in `package.json` to `node_modules`

## Part 2 - tracking versions of dependencies

### package.json

`package.json` tracks what versions of packages your project *should* be compatible with ([*semantically*-speaking](https://semver.org/)). Think of this as the package version specification.

### package-lock.json

`package-lock.json` tracks what versions of what packages were installed last time `npm install` was run, including transitive dependencies. This means the exact version, no ranges are used here. Think of this as the package version implementation.

### Choosing one or the other

You can use `npm ci` instead of `npm i` (or `npm install`) to install the exact versions instead of looking for the most recent versions that *should* be compatible.